# How To remove Scrollbar cause by Overflow?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, navbar

is there anyway i can remove the Second little Scrollbar appear when i set the overflow-x of fixed position my navigation bar to hidden?

**Image link:[Right Here!~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyGQf.png)**

**And this is my Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-style">
<nav>
    <img src="images/logo_3.png">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">About</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;

  html, body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
   }

  *, *:before, *:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box; }

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    #main-style{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5; /*The Highest Index*/
    }

    nav{
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        display: block;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

im current using chrome

**NOTE:**

All the height of element in the navigation bar was set correctly 60px.
**Hope you can help me out here.Thanks Alot!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this recently by changing the *html,body* to:

```
  overflow-y: visible;
```

and change the *nav* to:

```
     overflow-y: hidden;
```

Hope this help you and it helped me >:D

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for the `nav`, replace `overflow-x: hidden;` with `overflow-y: hidden;`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

Comment: Thank it deleted the little scrollbar but then the navbar would goes over the *MAIN* Scroll bar

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of what that looks like?